# Azure policy to require a specific tag, and a like condition

Tags: azure-policy

How can I add an Azure policy that will require the recourse group has:

1. A certain existing tag they must update
2. This tag must be like "*prod". So "environment1_prod" will be an acceptable value.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using the below two examples you can create the Azure Policy you want:

1. Add/Replace Resource Group Tag. (Find example [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-policy/tree/master/samples/Tags/add-replace-resourcegroup-tag))
2. Using like pattern (Find example [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-policy/blob/master/samples/TextPatterns/enforce-like-pattern/azurepolicy.json)).